# Tikz: drawing a straight line down in a rotated scope

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I would like to draw a straight line down from `(P)` to `y = -2cm`.  I tried issuing `\draw[rotate = -45, xshift = 0.1cm, >=stealth, |<->|] (P) -- +(0, -1cm);` but this doesn't cancel the initial rotation.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate = 45]
  \draw (-0.5cm, -1cm) rectangle (0.5cm, -2cm) coordinate (P);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

In my initial workings, I used `(0.5cm, -2cm)` and not the label `(P)`.  The coordinate values produce a different result and resulted in a new question: [Tikz: rotating point coordinates over a labelled coordinate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177421/tikz-rotating-point-coordinates-over-a-labelled-coordinate)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Paul Gessler pointed that out.  I asked a new question because it doesn't work if we use `(0.5, 2)` instead of `P`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the `\draw` outside the scope:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate = 45]
  \draw (-0.5cm, -1cm) rectangle (0.5cm, -2cm) coordinate (P);
\end{scope}
  \draw[>=stealth, |<->|] (P) -- +(0, -1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So what I take from this is if I label a point in a scope, that label will be defined by the overall action on it not just its point location, correct?

Comment: @dustin, this appears to give the exact same result I got using your `\draw[rotate = -45, xshift = 0.1cm, >=stealth, |<->|] (P) -- +(0, -1cm);` inside the scope. Just for my own knowledge, what is different here?

Comment: @PaulGessler you are right.  If we don't name the coordinate and just use `(0.5cm, -2cm)`, it doesn't work though.  That is why I was under the impression the opposite rotation wouldn't work.

Comment: @PaulGessler see my new question about this. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177421/tikz-rotating-point-coordinates-over-a-labelled-coordinate

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm,rotate = 45]
  \draw (-0.5cm, -1cm) rectangle (0.5cm, -2cm) coordinate (P);
  \draw[>=stealth,line width=2pt, blue, |<->|] (P) -- +(-135:1cm);
  \draw[>=stealth, |<->|] (0.5cm, -2cm) -- +(-135:1cm);    %%% -90 adds to -45 so -135
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]