# Tikz: rotating point coordinates over a labelled coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

From [Tikz: drawing a straight line down in a rotated scope](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177417/tikz-drawing-a-straight-line-down-in-a-rotated-scope#177418), Paul Gessler pointed out that rotating labelled coordinate `(P)` in the opposite direction of the initial rotation would counter act it.  However, if we do this to the point, it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate = 45]
  \draw (-0.5cm, -1cm) rectangle (0.5cm, -2cm) coordinate (P);

  \draw[rotate = -45] (P) -- +(0, -1);

  \draw[rotate = -45] (0.5cm, -2cm) -- +(0, -1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Considering `(P)` and `(-0.5cm, -2cm)` are the same location, why does using the coordinate point and not the name not work?

[image]

Comment: They are _not_ the same location; that is the issue.

Comment: @PaulGessler that is apparent but it doesn't make any sense.  They should be the same.

Comment: In this case you can use `rotate around`, as in `\draw[rotate around= {-45:(0.5cm, -2cm)}, xshift = 0.1cm, >=stealth, |<->|] (0.5cm, -2cm) -- +(0, -1cm);`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina both `(P)` and the hard coded location are defined as the same location.  Why does one need a different rotate for this?

Comment: @dustin In one case you rotate the line at the same you draw it. In the othe case, you put a mark (`ccordinate`) at a place, and you can move it, you can define a new point `(-45:P)` but `(P)` still at the place you've puted it. Same if you draw a line, after you can't move it, You have to draw another one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nodes don't move except if you say it explicitely.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate = 45]
  \draw (-0.5cm, -1cm) rectangle (0.5cm, -2cm) coordinate (P);

  \draw[rotate = -45,yellow] (P) -- ++(0, -1);
  \draw[rotate = -45,very thick,blue!50] (0.5cm, -2cm) -- ++(0, -1);
  \draw[rotate = -45,red] ([rotate = -45]P) -- ++(0, -1);

\end{scope}

  \draw[rotate = -45,yellow,dashed] (P) -- ++(0, -1);
  \draw[rotate = -45,very thick,blue!50,dashed] (0.5cm, -2cm) -- ++(0, -1);
  \draw[rotate = -45,red,dashed] ([rotate = -45]P) -- ++(0, -1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```